# Current - magnetic field intensity relation

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

This is my first question in this community and I hope to get a good answer.

I'm reading a book about the principles of electrical machines and it is in English while my first language is Arabic, so I need some clarifications.
I read this theory:

> "the line integral of the magnetic field intensity $H$ around a closed path is equal to the total current linked by the contour".

A picture is attached below for reference.

My question is not about Math, but i couldn't connect the figure to the theory so I can understand it in the best possible way.

Any clarification please?

[image]

Comment: Hi Ayman and welcome to Physics.SE. Please note that your question is asking two separate things and we prefer a focused approach. Please rephrase your question and consider asking about references in a later question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Current everywhere in conductor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/344990/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [Ampère's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law). It is a law which is condensed in Maxwell's equations, the four equations that explain all the classical electromagnetic events. This equation in differential form reads
$$\nabla \times \vec{H}=\vec{J_f}+\varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \vec{D}}{\partial t}$$
In magnetostatic situations, the derivative is zero, then you will have
$$\nabla \times \vec{H}=\vec{J_f}$$
Where $\vec{J_f}$ is the current density of the free charges. You can integrate this in a certain surface and use Stoke's integral theorem to get the equation you posted. This is an analogue law to Gauss' Law, which relates the electric field in a surface with the charge this surface encloses. Coming back to the magnetic case, what this law means is that when you have a magnetic field $\vec{H}$ and  choose a closed path, the result of the integral is the sum of the currents enclosed by the path. In the example you posted,  the path is around currents $i_1,i_2,i_3$, then the result of the integral is the sum of those.

Comment: Dear Alvaro, Thanks for the clarification, but mostly i wanted to know about the term "closed path" in that example. Is the drawn line like a wire? or this all was like a surface and the currents goes through it ?

Comment: Oh. The closed path is not any "touchable" or "physical" source. It's the trajectory over which you will integrate. You can imagine it as a closed rope which encloses some current, but it is just the path over which you are integrating. If you still don't know what I mean, I suggest you study line integrals.

Comment: thank you very much, can you please suggest any source which explains line integrals?

Comment: This is a very good [book](https://1lib.eu/book/1255026/ed0f9b) on math used in physics. Chapter 4 has integrals.

Comment: i will read it, thanks :). I hope if we may be in contact as i need some explanations from time to time. and you gave the answer in the most easiest way i could wish. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to post any conceptual doubt here or in Math's S.E. We'll be happy to help.